# How to integrate silverlight into aspx?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, integration

I have created a Silverlight application now I want to embed it into my aspx page. Is there any video tutorial for this, which explains how to integrate silverlight in aspx page?

Comment: By integrating, if you mean embedding, then you can embed using `<object />` tag. See this [msdn post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089%28VS.95%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: @Bala R: I have read it but I am looking for a video tutoria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your web project, make sure you've included a reference to the silverlight application so the .xap file will be in the clientbin folder.

Right-click on your web project and select Properties. Select the Silverlight Applications tab on the left. Click the Add... button and select your existing Silverlight project. Also, check the box that says, "Add a test page that references the control" and VS will include a new .ASPX page that will have the code to reference the Silverlight control.

Note: this assumes the silverlight project and the web project are in the same solution. I assume they are..

Comment: Is there any video tutorial for this process?

Comment: Possibly..  but its crazy easy to do. Its literally like 5 clicks :)  Did you try what I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how a chart control can be embedded in an aspx page:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/chart/examples/silverlight/defaultcs.aspx