# integrate silverlight xaml page with asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I am using web developer 2010.I folowed this thread: [How to integrate silverlight into aspx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099485/how-to-integrate-silverlight-into-aspx).

But it shows msgbox saying  already added reference.
when i try to run my aspx page I get an Error:Unknown server tag 'asp:Silverlight'.
I have .net framework 4, silverlight 3 and 4.

I have code in .aspx as:

```
    <div><asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager"/>
<asp:Silverlight runat="server" ID="silverlightLayout" InstallationMode="Inline" Version="1.1" Source="MainPage.xaml"
        EnableHtmlAccess="true" Windowless="true" Width="844" Height="472" PluginBackColor="Transparent" /> </div>
```

what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy ,can you locate the TestPage.aspx and .xap file in your silverlight bin folder ,in your silverlight project ,open you aspx file ,you will see tag having xap file use it in same pattern in required project and copy that xap file you required projects bin folder 
[CLick to view exmaple](http://www.silverlight.net/archives/videos/add-a-silverlight-application-to-an-aspnet-page) please mark the answer if it helps

Comment: I have inserted a link in my above answer ,please click it. Happy Coding